# Not getting emails from emailjs and smtp-server - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to build an app that sends an email when something is triggered.

I'm not getting any errors, but getting no emails to my inbox.

This is the code:

SMTP:

```
var SMTPServer = require('smtp-server').SMTPServer;
var server = new SMTPServer({
    secure: false, authOptional: true
});
server.listen(465);
```

emailjs:

```
var email = require('emailjs');

var emailServer = email.server.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 465,
    ssl: false
});

emailServer.send({
    text: 'Hey howdy',
    from: 'NodeJS',
    to: 'Wilson <person@gmail.com>',
    cc: '',
    subject: 'Greetings'
}, function (err, message) {
    console.log(err || message);
});
```

The output I see on my console is:

```
{ attachments: [],
  alternative: null,
  header:
   { 'message-id': '<1470995427701.0.2864@DESKTOP-M85CNRC>',
     date: 'Fri, 12 Aug 2016 12:50:27 +0300',
     from: '=?UTF-8?Q?NodeJS?= <>',
     to: '=?UTF-8?Q?Wilson?= <person@gmail.com>',
     cc: '',
     subject: '=?UTF-8?Q?Greetings?=' },
  content: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  text: 'Hey howdy' }
```

Any idea about what's missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am using `nodemailer-smtp-transport` and is working perfectly for me, follow is my configuration inside the function through which i am sending mail. Hope this may help.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");

//configuration
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport ({
        auth: {
            user: user,   //email of sender
            pass: pass    //password of sender
        },
        host: host,    //my email host
        secureConnection: true,
        port: 587,
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        },
    }));    

    var mailOptions = {
        from: user,
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        text: text
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
         if(error){
           console.log(error);
        }else{
           console.log("success");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to follow your answer, but still didn't work. the smtp I set up is from the smtp-server module, it requires no credentials. how do I connect with it without credentials?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can send mails without credentials, i know in php you can send emails without credentials but not sure with node.js, anyways, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

In emailjs file host cannot be **localhost** it should be like :**smtp.your-email.com**.

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "username", 
   password:"password", 
   host:    "smtp.your-email.com", 
   ssl:     true
});
```

Comment: How do I know the smtp host, As I understand, the smtp-server module creates it on the localhost, true?

Answer (score 0):

I use an Gmail account not very important for my tests in stead of module smtp-server.

**First**: Required activate the use less secure apps at your own risk as indicated in the Gmail documentation:

https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/lesssecureapps?pageId=none

**After:**

```
var email   = require("emailjs");
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "YOUR_ACCOUNT@gmail.com", 
   password:"YOUR_PASSWORD", 
   host:    "smtp.gmail.com",
   ssl:     true
});

server.send({
   text:    "Hello world", 
   from:    "YOUR_NAME <YOUR_ACCOUNT@gmail.com>", 
   to:      "FRIEND_NAME <FRIEND_ACCOUNT@gmail.com>",
   subject: "Hello"
}, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```